# How to split URL from one line URL in php

Tags: php

How to split this URL. So that its redirect to different website

```
  http://www.google.comhttp://www.yahoo.comhttp://www.youtube.comhttp://www.gmail.com
```

Comment: Please explain better your question. Read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: There is no easy way to split that string. Even regular expressions won't help much, considering there is no split, unless you want to have each possible TLD as an explicit match.

Re-think your string. Use JSON, YAML, CSV, etc to create a coherent string and **then** parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following code

```html
<?php
$a='http://www.google.comhttp://www.yahoo.comhttp://www.youtube.comhttp://www.gmail.com';
$a = explode('http',$a);
for($i=1;$i<count($a);$i++){
    echo 'http'.$a[$i].PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```